# Which is better for bootstrap, a cdn or self hosted?

Tags: css, performance, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, cdn

I'm new to bootstrap but could use some tips on getting started. From a performance perspective, is it better to import ALL of bootstrap using the MaxCDN, or download and host only the components I plan on using?

I do plan on customizing the appearance quite a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is a difficult question, because the answer is: it depends.

Using external CDN has two advantages:

1. users which has visited site, which uses same CDN, will already have
   JS and CSS in cache
2. you don't use your own network load

But there is also 2 main problems:

1. If user has blocked access t CDN (prox, firewall, CDN is dead) it is difficult to find it out
2. Most CDN doesn't have JS and CSS budles, which optimize request count (sometime ago I found CDN which serves bundles: http://piotrstapp.azurewebsites.net/cdn-bundles-are-avaliable/)

So to sum up: you have to check it yourself how fast your website will load using bundles, using CDN, etc. And then make a decision

Comment: One of the advantage of using a CDN is also to go up against the default (between 4 and 8) maximum concurrent connection of the browsers. One default with that also being the cost of an extra DNS lookup needed.

Comment: Why you think that that you have more maximum concurrent connections for CDN?

Comment: You don't. Your browser does have a maximum concurrent connection on a same URL. So if your site http://example.com hosts its file on http://example.org, then you can have twice the amount of maximum concurrent connection of your browser.